# Spring 3.0 Helloworld example

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my first attempt at using Spring. I'm probably making a stupid mistake, however I can't find it.

I'm using the GlassFish edition 3.1.2 as server. When I run the program I get the index page. On this page I click on the link and then I get the error:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/nameProject/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Thank you for your help.

These are my files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />          

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="example" />

</beans>
```

HelloWorldController.java:

```
package example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello(){
        String message = "Good evening sir.";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

}
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say hello</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <a href="hello.html">Say hello</a> shouldn't that be  <a href="hello.jsp">Say hello</a> ?

Comment: @Steve No, that doesn't work. When using hello.html, Spring should contact the right controller (in this case HelloWorldController) and by return the MVC hello, the hello.jsp page is returned because this is specified in the servlet file. (in theorie, but at the moment it isn't working) PS. correct if I'm wrong, but this is how I understood it.

Comment: I think the request mapping line should be @RequestMapping("/hello.html") then

Comment: @su No. By having to use /hello.html you would limit the use of Spring. I'm pretty sure the mapping must be "/hello".

Comment: If mapping must be /hello, I believe you need to change <a href="hello.html">Say hello</a> to <a href="/hello">Say hello</a>, and <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: @su- I tried that, but then the index page doesn't load. So I also changed <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop> to <prop key="index">indexController</prop> but this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you use both XML and annotation configurations, and those annotation configuration is not enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable spring mvc annotations, these lines are needed in the spring configuration

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="example" />
```

---

edit:

1.following XML is also needed to enable @RequestMapping annotations at the class level and the method level

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

2.remove wrong advice about changing indexController

3.please change the class to:

```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/hello"), you still can use class level mapping, but it's optional
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello") //a must-set, also can be something like ("/hello/index")
    public ModelAndView hello(){ //method renamed, the original name is same as Constructor name, which is not recommended
        String message = "Good evening sir.";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct about the url-pattern ant the mvc annotations thx. But you are wrong about the indexController (tried it and it failed as it should). This is because I dont have an indexController myself. Spring has a standard indexController that gets configured by the statement above. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Sorry I could be wrong about that. Haven't used those for a while. To use annotation, you also need to add these two lines: <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

Comment: Ok, so I have added the beans and removed the changes of the indexController. But still the same problem. I edited the listings in my question so you know how my files look at this moment.

Comment: You are using org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView not org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView?

Comment: Nice catch! I changed it but I'm afraid something is still wrong.

Comment: OK, this time it should work. I already tested in my local. Please see my edit...

Comment: Ok, it still doens't work. But I get an error ;). At least now I have something I can google. We're getting closer. The error is: "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/nameProject/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'".

Comment: Strange. I already saw 'Good evening sir.' in my browser. If you manually change url to /nameProject/hello.htm (in browser's address bar), will you get the same error?

Comment: Wait, dispatcher-servlet.xml doesn't have xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, you only put it in applicationContext.xml, but mvc:annotation-driven is used in dispatcher-servlet.xml. That should cause problem

Comment: It works when I change @RequestMapping("/hello") to @RequestMapping("/hello/*")

Comment: I'll add those to the dispatcher servlet to avoid problems in the future. However at this moment everything works as it should. I can't thank you enough for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Your file extension on href is `.html`, so, dispatcher servlet should allow .`html` pattern

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Added it to the file, but this doesn't help.